# Angular Universal: MouseEvent is not defined

Tags: angular, dom, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am running the command `dev:ssr` and getting the following exception in my Angular 10 Project:

```
Compiled successfully.
./dist/Project/server/main.js:220253
Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__metadata"])("design:paramtypes", [MouseEvent]), 

ReferenceError: MouseEvent is not defined
```

I am aware that there are similar issues out there with messages like `win/document/etc. is undefined`, however, the solutions for those issues did not work for me.

I tried using `isPlatformBrowser()` and mocking browser behaviour with `domino`, however, no effect.

My ng version:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.2.0
Node: 12.19.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.2.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1002.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1002.0
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.1002.0
@angular-devkit/core               10.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics         10.2.0
@angular/cdk                       10.2.5
@angular/fire                      5.4.2
@angular/flex-layout               10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/material                  10.1.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   10.2.5
@nguniversal/builders              10.1.0
@nguniversal/express-engine        10.1.0
@schematics/angular                10.2.0
@schematics/update                 0.1002.0
ng-packagr                         10.1.2
rxjs                               6.6.3
typescript                         3.9.7
```

Any other ideas anyone?

UPDATE:

One of the libraries, where MouseEvent is used, has 2 occurences of it.

The first one is the following (needed to detect if the user clicked outside of the component, to close it):

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickedOutside(event: MouseEvent) {
    const clickedInside = this.innerClasses.some(innerClass => (event.target as HTMLElement).classList.contains(innerClass));
    if (!this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) && !clickedInside) {
      this.closeDialog();
    }
  }
```

The other one is to focus on the input:

```
  onContainerClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if ((event.target as Element).tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input') {
      this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').focus();
    }
  }
```

As I metioned, I already tried to use `isPlatformBrowser()`, however, it does not have any effect, and I am still seeing that error message.

Comment: i think we need more informations but MouseEvent is not allowed in ssr mode because Window object not exist in SSR

Comment: @Twen is right. Every direct calls to document or window object will result in an error once you render your page with the ssr (those are only client objects). You need to use build in angular events like (click) in your code to prevent this type of error to happen.

Comment: @QuentinFonck, I am using Angular built-in events. However, in some cases, I have custom components, which I am re-using in the app, and those components include methods that consist of parameters of MouseEvent type. Or sometimes MouseEvent also comes in `@HostListeners`. Therefore, I am not sure what to do with that part, in order for it to work properly with Angular SSR.

Comment: Why would you need a @hostListener for a click event ? Can you provide an example to illustrate those use cases in your question ? We can't really tell if this could be the problem. Most of the time,  encapsulating the code with an if statement and `isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)` helps for this kind of issue.

Comment: @QuentinFonck I updated the question. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code.
It is not recommended to by pass Angular by accessing directly to the DOM. It is for this specific reason that you get issues with SSR. Always use data binding and event binding when you can.
Can't you use event binding instead of the @hostListener for this use case?

If you cannot do otherwhise, use at least the renderer2 service to access the DOM (https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2). Do not use `nativeElement` directly.
It will also help you to protect your app against cross-site scripting.
Forget also .querySelector() to request dom element. Use `@ViewChild` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to follow your recommendations. The second method (```onContainerClick```), though, I took from angular material docs for creating custom controls (https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control).

Comment: Since it is a front end library, it won't always take ssr requirements in consideration. A idea would be to unplug possible faulty components, see if ssr works and plug them back one by one until it crashes again. Setting up angular-universal is a real pain once you get pretty far in your development.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was actually helpful! And even though I did not yet complete the setup of Angular Universal after fixing it, I was still able to proceed further.

Comment: Happy to know that it helped :)